# css3 or jquery opacity animation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok I have this code for the html.

```
<a class="fade fade1" href="#"></a>
<a class="fade fade2" href="#"></a>
<a class="fade fade3" href="#"></a>
```

and this css for those html element above

```
a.fade
{
width: 249px;
height: 90px;
float: none;
clear: both;
margin: 8px auto;
overflow: auto;
display: block;

/*fade*/
/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
    /* ...but not required as filter works too */
    /* should come BEFORE filter */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

    /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
    /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);

    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity:0.5;

    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

    /* Modern!
    /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
    /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
a.fade1
{
background: transparent url(http://jameskbrooks.com/wp-    content/uploads/2012/11/MC2151023682-e1353394381773.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
a.fade2
{
background: transparent url(http://jameskbrooks.com/wp-    content/uploads/2012/11/MC2151023684-e1353394564665.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
a.fade3
{
background: transparent url(http://jameskbrooks.com/wp-            content/uploads/2012/11/MC2151023683-e1353394572666.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
a.fade:hover
{

/*fade*/
/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
    /* ...but not required as filter works too */
    /* should come BEFORE filter */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";

    /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
    /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity:1.0;

    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 1.0;

    /* Modern!
    /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
    /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
    opacity: 1.0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 600ms linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 600ms linear;
  transition: opacity 600ms linear;

}
```

So based on those css3 declared above, by default the a.fade is set to opacity by half and then whenever a user hover or mouseover to those elements, the opacity is set to full with an animation on it like fade in from half opacity to full opacity but the problem is whenever I withdraw my mouse from those element, there is no animation like fade out from full opacity then back to its default opacity which is 50%. I know this could be done by jquery so Im looking someone around here to give me a clue on how to do it. css3 preferred.

Hope I could find something that can solve my issue, thank you.

Im open in any ideas, recommendation and suggestions.

Comment: Try setting the transition to `a.fade` instead of `a.fade:hover`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides `fadeIn()` ,`fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` for you to change opacity of any object.
Just trigger `fadeIn()` ,`fadeOut()` or `fadeIn()` for `$("a.fade").hover()`.

For example,

```
$("a.fade").hover(
    function() { $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); },
    function() { $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1); }
);
```

For your reference, http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it in jQuery:

```
$('#container')
  .on('mouseover', 'a.fade', function(){
   $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}, 500) // animate to 100%, in 500 ms
  })
  .on('mouseout', 'a.fade', function(){
   $(this).animate({'opacity': 0.5}, 500) // animate to 50%, in 500 ms
  })
```